# Как подключить mathjax библиотеку в android приложение?

Tags: java, android, latex, mathjax

1) Как подключить mathjax библиотеку в android приложение?

2) Выводить кусок текста с latex в webview или во что-то еще можно?

Не могу найти литературу на понятном английском.

Comment: Хм... Я точно видел тут вопрос про это же с ответом из трёх ссылок.

Comment: https://github.com/leathrum/android-apps

Answer (score 1):

1) [В доках MathJax всё есть](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/start.html). Если коротко, вам нужно создать WebView, прицепить к странице которую вы отображаете MathJax.js и всё, вероятно если выкачать MathJax.js к себе то можно будет рендерить формулки оффлайн, но я не уверен мб всё сложнее.

2) Если речь идёт именно про MathJax то только в WebView.